# jQuery shorthand to full code

Tags: javascript, jquery, shorthand

Can anyone please help me read this shorthand code?

```
datain = $this.hasClass('up')?+1:($this.hasClass('down')?-1:null);
```

sorry for the obvious question but I can't work it out myself.

I wish the datain to return "+1" if it has the up class but instead it only returns "1"

Comment: if the element has the class 'up' datain = 1, otherwise, if it has 'down' datain = -1, if neither datain = null

Comment: How can I set it so that datain = +1 if it has class up? It doesn't work when I simply put "+1"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: That's a couple nested ternary operators, Felix posted a great resource to learn more.

Comment: to add one to datain: `datain = ($this.hasClass('up') datain+1 :` ... what was already there. Same for -1 -- you need to put datain there. Your other option is to do: `($this.hasClass('up) ? datain +=1 : ($this.hasClass('down')) ? datain -= 1 : datain = null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is using the [conditional operator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28programming%29#If_expressions)

```
if($this.hasClass("up")) {
   datain = 1;
} else {
   if($this.hasClass("down"))
      datain = -1;
   else
      datain = null;
}
```

If you want datain to return +1, then you probably need to assign it a string instead of an integer. Just wrap the values in quotes. (`"+1"`, `"-1"`)

Comment: Nitpick: It's the *conditional* operator, which is *a* ternary operator :)

Comment: @FelixKling, oh thanks. I didn't know that. Guess I should read my own Wikipedia links.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to :

```
// This variable $this looks strange, some php naming involved in JS ?
if ($this.hasClass('up')) {
    //I hope datain is meant to be global or correctly declared with the var keyword above
    datain = 1;
} else if ($this.hasClass('down')) {
    datain = -1
} else {
    datain = null;
}
```